# Turning a python project to exe with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, numexpr

I'm trying to turn a python project to exe but I get this problem when running the .exe file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fiveopoker.py", line 4, in <module>
File "agents.pyc", line 10, in <module>
File "probTable.pyc", line 3, in <module>
File "tables\__init__.pyc", line 26, in <module>
File "numexpr\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
ImportError: No module named __config__
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named __config__`

Comment: So which python module is referencing `__config__`?

Comment: @Drewness I have no idea, I am new to py2exe, and I don't really understand what it means

Comment: Im just gonna leave this here and back slowly out of the room http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259333/frustration-trying-to-create-gui-for-python-script/22259458#22259458

Comment: And if you create a python script with `import scipy` and run it do you get the same error?

Comment: no, the script runs well